# How to get some php multidimensional arrays?

Tags: php, arrays, multidimensional-array

How to call all the tags at once?

I curently do something like this:

```
$artist['tags']['0']['name'];
$artist['tags']['1']['name'];
// and so on for all 5 (0-4)


[tags] => Array
        (
            [0] => Array
                (
                    [name] => hip-hop
                    [url] => http://www.last.fm/tag/hip-hop
                )

            [1] => Array
                (
                    [name] => romanian
                    [url] => http://www.last.fm/tag/romanian
                )

            [2] => Array
                (
                    [name] => romanian hip-hop
                    [url] => http://www.last.fm/tag/romanian%20hip-hop
                )

            [3] => Array
                (
                    [name] => rap
                    [url] => http://www.last.fm/tag/rap
                )

            [4] => Array
                (
                    [name] => hip hop
                    [url] => http://www.last.fm/tag/hip%20hop
                )

        )
```

Comment: i mean... something like "hip-hop, romanian, romanian hip-hop, rap, hip hop"

Comment: sorry, after reading the answers I realised what you mean and removed my comment. :) The answers should help.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use a [`foreach`](http://php.net/foreach) loop to iterate through all the tags of an artist:

```
$tags = array();
foreach ($artist['tags'] as $tag)
{
   $tags[] = $tag['name'];
}
echo implode(', ', $tags);
```

Comment: it has a little problem:  Notice: Array to string conversion in the last line ...  Array, Array, Array, Array, Array

Comment: +1 this code will also will take care of not printing the comma in the end :)

Answer (score 1):

Use [foreach](http://php.net/manual/en/control-structures.foreach.php) and iterate over them.

It seems like you want to use this:

```
foreach($artist['tags'] as $key => $value)
    echo $value['name'] . ', ';
```

Answer (score 1):

```
foreach ($artist['tags'] as $tag) {
    echo $tag['name'];
}
```

I think this is what you are asking for...

Comment: how to display a comma between them?

Answer (score 1):

```
foreach($artist['tags'] as $key => $value)
 echo $value['name'] . '&nbsp;';
```

this will loop through array and will write tags into response

Comment: they work, the only problem they are listed as "hip-hopromanianromanian hip-hopraphip hop" ; not with a comma and space between them

Comment: I have added space to separate them, you can add '<br>' tag or anything else, or format it as you like